# PHP curl version changed program not working

Tags: php, curl

I have written an application in PHP in a virtual machine using EASY PHP (I know I shouldn't use Windows but Linux instead :)). Now I have moved my program to a linux real server (in fact, this is my synology diskstation) and nothing is working anymore. I did some debugging and it seems I don't get anything back from the curl function.

In my windows server, the curl version was 7.21 and now on the synology, the version is 7.26-DEV. Maybe it is because I am using the DEV version?

Here is a part of the code, I am using very basic curl so I don't know if I need to do something to activate curl. When I do a phpinfo on my linux server, I can see curl support enabled.

Code:'

```
   $ch = curl_init();
   if ($debug == 1) 
   {
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
   }
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_request);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, './cookie/cookie.txt'); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$ihcip."ws/AuthenticationService");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 

   if (preg_match('`^https://`i', $ihcip)) 
   { 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
   } 

   if ($debug == 1) {
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'dbg_curl_data');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'dbg_curl_data');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
   }

   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   if ($debug == 1) 
   {
      echo '<fieldset><legend>request headers</legend> <pre>', htmlspecialchars(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)), '</pre> </fieldset>';
      echo '<fieldset><legend>xml request</legend> <pre>', htmlspecialchars($xml_request), '</pre> </fieldset>';
      echo '<fieldset><legend>response</legend> <pre>', htmlspecialchars(dbg_curl_data(null)), '</pre> </fieldset>';
   }
```

'

Comment: What exactly doesn't work anymore ? What output do you expect ? Do you get any error (make sure error reporting is on) ? And btw maybe you need to add a forward slash before **ws**: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$ihcip."/ws/AuthenticationService");`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the remark but I included the / in the variable $ihcip. Maybe it is not a good idea but it is working fine on the other server.

Comment: I did some more testing and when I ask for the last error it says: Curl error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to 10.0.0.254:443 even though in phpinfo, I can see it is installed with SSL. It says: SSL Version OpenSSL/1.0.1c. Do you know what I need to do in order for SSL to work?

Comment: I have specified now the version of ssl with setopt_ssl version to 3 and I received this text: response
HTTP/1.1 501 Method POST is not defined in RFC 2068 and is not supported by the Servlet API 
content-type: text/html
date: Mon, 04-Feb-2013 23:41:47 GMT
keep-alive: timeout=900, max=1000
connection: Keep-Alive
content-length: 366
server: Rogatkin's JWS based on Acme.Serve/$Revision: 1.39 $
mime-version: 1.0. It is strange because as I said, it is working with the exact same code on the other server. Do I need to set up some other variables? Which one do you think?